# Program type already present Android

Tags: android, braintree

I am facing issue in app after adding two library into the my application.Before adding this libs my app working well.

I add :

```
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:4.1.0'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
```

After that i am facing following issue, I try to solve out it but not success at all.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:


Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
```

If any Solutions of it then please post answer here.

My Build.gradle file information :

```
compileSdkVersion 28

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appname"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28

    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.0.7"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: add `android.enableJetifier=true` in your `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: @Dhaiyur after that  i am getting : AndroidX must be enabled when Jetifier is enabled. To resolve, set android.useAndroidX=true in your gradle.properties file.

Comment: my application not using androidx so if it is used by braintree then its conflict with my app ?

Comment: i am enable android.useAndroidX=true  but i am getting so many issue in my import library project

Comment: braintree version 4.1.1 support androidx.

Comment: so downgrade the version of it, is my solutions ?

Comment: i required braintree without androidx otherwise it conflict my current app library

Comment: try to upgrade to 4.1.1

Comment: not found 4.1.1 for drop-in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191705/discussion-between-dhaiyur-and-topsy).